# unable to start kibana process

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-4

I am trying to install kibana using rpm kibana-4.5.0-1.x86_64.rpm.
However when i try to start the Kibana process, i am getting below prompt
**Starting kibana....... unable to start process kibana**.

To check the reason i have enabled log file by setting the below parameter in kibana.yml : 
**logging.dest: /opt/kibana/kibana.log**

However no log file is getting created and i am unable to identify why kibana process is not starting.

Any suggestion would be appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

Please check ---
RPM install is not supported on distributions with old versions of RPM, such as SLES 11 and CentOS 5.

My suggetion you can install Kibana with .tar.gz
Can follow the link :

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/targz.html

Comment: I need to install Kibana version 4.5.0

Comment: What is your OS ? give us the complete details about your system environment.

Comment: Redhat Linux 1.6 is the env.

i have installed Elasticsearch-2.3.1 for which i need Kibana 4.5.0

Comment: ...Sir Any update on this? Or any additional details required?

Comment: Have you tried to install Kibana in other available ways ?  Like:   https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/install.html

Comment: Yes Sir, i tried running the binaries and now it is working fine:)